# Socialite Driver [VKontakte] not supported Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6

Использую `Socialite Manager driver` для авторизации в ВК. Получаю следующую ошибку `Driver [VKontakte] not supported`

Делал по гайду https://socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/v-kontakte.html

Вот основной код

```
my app.php\SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class, // add

my EventServiceProvider
protected $listen = [
    \SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled::class => [
        // add your listeners (aka providers) here
        'SocialiteProviders\\VKontakte\\VKontakteExtendSocialite@handle',
    ],
];

Controller
return Socialite::with('VKontakte')->redirect();
```

Comment: Что именно выполняли по гайду и что добавляли покажите

Comment: Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. По-моему, в гайде косяк. Попробуй
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50958157/socialite-driver-vkontakte-not-supported/51050769#51050769

Comment: Почему-то ваша ссылка не работает, вы точно делали по этой документации? https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Documentation/blob/master/docs/providers/v-kontakte.md

Answer (score 1):

Выполните команду

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: пробовал, не помогло